# How can I make this VHDL code synthesizable?

Tags: vhdl

I have VHDL code that uses havily the fallowing syntax:

```
     signal_1   <= (others => '0')     when cau_state = st_idle       else
                  signal_2 - signal_3  when cau_state = st_cycle_1    else
                  signal_4             when cau_state = st_cycle_2    else
                  signal_5             when cau_state = st_cycle_3    else
                  signal_6             when cau_state = st_cycle_4    else
                  signal_1;
```

Where `cau_state` is a signal that holds the current state. This syntax worked in simulation on Model-Sim and everything worked fine. But when I wanted to burn the code to an FPGA, the code didn't synthesize on Altera Quartus II 32-bit ver. 12.1 And I got the fallowing error messages:

```
Warning (13012): Latch CAU:uut|cross_3_sig[0][31] has unsafe behavior
Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal CAU:uut|cau_state.st_cycle_2
Warning (13012): Latch CAU:uut|cross_3_sig[0][30] has unsafe behavior
Warning (13013): Ports D and ENA on the latch are fed by the same signal CAU:uut|cau_state.st_cycle_2
```

I get these messages for many signals, but **NOT** for all the signals that are using this syntax. And for a signal that get this message I get it for all its bits: `cross_3_sig[0][31]` to `cross_3_sig[0][0]`. The syntax for the signal `cross_3_sig(0)` is:

```
constant WIDTH          : integer := 32;
...
subtype scalar          is std_logic_vector((WIDTH-1) downto 0);                                  
type    vector_nd       is array (natural range <>) of scalar;
subtype vector_3d       is vector_nd(2 downto 0);
...
signal cross_3_sig          : vector_3d;
...
cross_3_sig(0)      <= sum_mults_out_sig              when cau_state = st_cycle_2  else              
                       mult1_out_sig - mult2_out_sig  when cau_state = st_cycle_9  else                          
                       cross_3_sig(0);
```

And there are some places where I assign `cross_3_sig(0)` into other signals, i.e.:

```
numer_sig           <= C_ZERO - cross_3_sig(0) & (16 downto 0 => '0'); 
mult1_in2_sig       <= (others => '0') when cau_state = st_idle       else
                       ...
                       cross_3_sig(0)  when cau_state = st_cycle_11   else
                       ...
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this form of expression creates a latch (which is sensitive to glitches on its control signal)  and furthermore it is a latch with multiple control signals, for which there is no direct equivalent in real hardware.

```
 signal_1   <= (others => '0')     when cau_state = st_idle       else
              ...
              signal_6             when cau_state = st_cycle_4    else
              signal_1;
```

Any time you see (outside a clocked process) something like

```
signal_1   <= ... else signal_1;
```

you know you have a problem. This is a signal feeding itself directly, an attempt to use a simple wire as a memory.

The correct use for this pattern is as a multiplexer, not as memory,

```
output_1 <= input_1 when ... else
            input_2 when ... else
            input_n;
```

The correct way to remember the old value of signal1 is a clocked process, e.g.

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if    cau_state = st_idle    then signal_1   <= (others => '0') 
        ...
        elsif cau_state = st_cycle_4 then signal_1  <= signal_6;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

With no assignment, signal_1 will maintain its current value.

Or a better alternative : use a case statement in the process:

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        case cau_state is
           when st_idle    => signal_1   <= (others => '0') 
           ...
           when st_cycle_4 => signal_1  <= signal_6;
           -- when others => some default action
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

This does change the semantics to a clocked design, but unclocked designs are troublesome in FPGA, to say the least!

Comment: What I did is to add `and rising_edge(CLK)` to all the `when` statements, so that it looks like: `signal_1 <= (others => '0') when cau_state = st_idle and rising_edge(CLK) else signal_1;` Is this the same as putting it inside a process and a case?

Comment: If it works and both sim and synth support it, yes I believe so.   Also, it appears I owe "sharth" an apology - you CAN now use the conditional assignment style in a process - IF your tools support VHDL-2008! Call me a dinosaur but I (like a lot of the tools still out there) still don't know all of VHDL-2008. To "sharth" : if you undelete your answer I'll upvote it...